# iOS `UICollectionView` rotation problems

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `UICollectionViewController` and I try to put two cells each line with Autolayout to support rotation.

```
// portrait
+-------------+
|+----+ +----+|
||cell| |cell||
|+----+ +----+|
+-------------+

// Landspace
+-------------------+
|+-------+ +-------+|
||cell   | |cell   ||
|+-------+ +-------+|
+-------------------+
```

So I use some `NSLayoutConstraint` for the cells. and `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`&`viewWillTransitionToSize` for rotation:

```
// MARK: - Rotation
// iOS7
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}

// iOS8
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Things goes well until I pushed another ViewController, I found if I rotation in new ViewController and goes back(with default NavigationBar), the UICollectionViewController cannot exec either `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `viewWillTransitionToSize`.

So how can I fit the right size when I go back through NavigationBar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29201486/1824510 this will help you.

Comment: invalidateLayout on viewWillAppear of the viewController.